# When using CsvHelper with autodetected delimiter, how can you find the delimiter used?

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

Relates to CsvHelper - https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

We can use delimiter autodetection when reading a file, but after the reading is complete, is it possible to detect the delimiter used?

I've tried accessing `csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter`, but it returns the default comma even after reading a file that uses a pipe as the delimiter.

Comment: i dont know the CsvHelper. But a quick look at the tests look's promising https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/tests/CsvHelper.Tests/Parsing/DetectDelimiterTests.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can get the delimiter that was autodetected from the `CsvParser`.

```cs
var delimiter = csvReader.Context.Parser.Delimiter;
```